# При заходе на сайт в файлах .js и .css почему-то находится код из файла index.html

Tags: .htaccess

Пишу веб приложение с использованием webpack 5, после сборки проекта в папке dist лежат файлы index.html, main.js и main.css, загрузил эту папку на хостинг и добавил файл .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^api/ api/index.php [L]
RewriteRule .* dist/index.html [L]
```

После попытки зайти на сайт в консоле вижу ошибку `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'     main.js:1` а если посмотреть на файл main.js во вкладке sources, то видно что весь js код заменился на html из файла index.html. С файлом main.css такая же беда. Почему так?

Вот ссылка на сам сайт: <ссылка удалена>

Вот конфигурация webpack (хотя дело наверное не в вебпаке):

```
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'

const filename = ext => isDev ? '[name].' + ext : '[name].[hash].' + ext

const cssLoaders = loaders => {
    let basicLoaders = [
        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        'css-loader',
        {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
                postcssOptions: {
                    plugins: [
                        ['autoprefixer', {}]
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]

    if (loaders) {
        basicLoaders.push(loaders)
    }

    return basicLoaders
}

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    devServer: {
        port: 4200,
        hot: true
    },
    devtool: isDev ? 'source-map' : undefined,
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
            '@models': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/models'),
            '@controllers': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/controllers'),
            '@helpers': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/helpers'),
        }
    },
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    entry: {
        main: './index.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: filename('js'),
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        clean: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './index.html'
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: filename('css')
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: 'html-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: '/node-modules/',
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                        plugins: ['@babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: cssLoaders()
            },
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/,
                use: cssLoaders('sass-loader')
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png|svg|jpeg|gif)$/,
                type: 'asset/resource'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: `RewriteRule .* dist/index.html [L]` как вы думаете, что делает эта строчка?

Comment: Редиректит любой запрос на файл dist/index.html, сохраняя при этом uri. Дело в этой строчке? Я не совсем разбираюсь в .htaccess

Comment: Ключевое слово «любой запрос». В том числе запросы за js/css

Comment: Понял, спасибо, но как тогда сделать правильно?

Comment: Добавил строчку перед последним rewriterule: `RewriteRule ([^\/]*\.(js|css|jpg|png|svg))$ dist/$1 [L]` всё заработало, но это явно костыльная строчка, неужели нет более правильного способа?

Comment: Обычно перед рерайтом вставляют проверку на существование файла `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`